# How to show my button when textfield clear button was pressed?

Tags: ios, xcode, textfield

I check my textfield like this:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([subtitleField.text length] == 0)
    {
        searchAddress.hidden = NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        searchAddress.hidden = YES;
    }

   return  YES;   
}
```

but it works only if I clear textfield by clear key, if I press clear button, it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the `[UITextFieldDelegate textFieldShouldClear:]` method as well:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    searchAddress.hidden = NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Ok.. your code work for clear button, but mine doesn't work for clear key like I expected. My searchAddress button appears only if I put some text, but I need to show my button only if my textfield is empty.

Comment: @PavelKaljunen Sounds like you need to mess with the `UITextField clearButtonMode` in your delegate methods then.